# C# Tcp Async socket data read logic

Tags: c#, c++, sockets

I'm working on a C# Tcp Async socket server program which will simply read socket data and put it into a file. Now the issue is before sending actual file content I'm sending client name and file name. Please note that I'm sending these data from C++ MFC application with simple send() API in below manner.

```
CString csInitData = "Client_Name | File_Name <EOF>";
send(hSocket, (LPCTSTR)csInitData, csInitData.GetLength(), 0);
```

Now how do I receive this data inside below async callback function? Cannot figure out the byte break up logic.

```
public void OnDataReceived(IAsyncResult ar)
{
  StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
  Socket clientSocket = state.m_currentSocket;

  int bytesRead = clientSocket.EndReceive(ar);
  if (bytesRead > 0)
  {
    //HERE I WANT TO RECEIVE THOSE DATA AND CREATE FOLDER AND FILE WITH THOSE NAMES RECEIVED FROM CLIENT
    //Process 'state.dataBuffer'//DATA INSIDE THIS BYTE BUFFER

    string fileName = "";       //FILE NAME SHOULD GO HERE
    string folderName = "";     //CLIENT NAME SHOULD GO HERE

    BinaryWriter writer;

    if (!File.Exists(folderName+fileName))
    { 
      Directory.CreateDirectory(folderName);
      writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(folderName+fileName, FileMode.Create));
    } 
    else
    {
      writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(folderName+fileName, FileMode.Append));
    }

    writer.Write(state.dataBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
    writer.Flush();
    writer.Close();

    // Recursively receive the rest file. 
    try
    {
      clientSocket.BeginReceive(state.dataBuffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(OnDataReceived), state);
    }
    catch
    {
      if (!clientSocket.Connected)
      {
        MessageBox.Show("Catched from OnDataReceived!");
      }
    }
  }
  else
  {
    // Signal if all the file received. 
  }
}
```

Comment: "Cannot figure out the byte break up logic." - can you be more specific what you are having difficulty with? There are a *lot* of things I would do differently here, but I'd rather focus on your main problem. Which is...?

Comment: As I'm receivng data from client socket I would like to save bytes in form of string upto <EOF> in a single variable so that I can process further with it and continue to read next socket datas.

Comment: string is inappropriate for binary data; I suspect you just want to use `MemoryStream` as a buffer, if I understand your comment correctly

Answer (score 1):

For the buffering, it sounds like you want `MemoryStream`:

```
// Somewhere to put the data:
// for simplicity, I'll assume an instance field is fine; could
// also be tracked via async-state object, if preferred
private MemoryStream backlog = new MemoryStream();

if (bytesRead > 0)
{
    // we want to append, so move to the end
    backlog.Position = backlog.Length;

    // copy new data into the buffer
    backlog.Write(state.dataBuffer, 0, bytesRead);

    ...         
}
```

General feedback:

- don't use `BinaryWriter` here; just `Stream` is fine
- use `using` on the file-stream
- have a cached delegate instance in a field so you don't need to `new` a delegate each time (this can even be `static` if you pass the target instance as state)
- use `Path.Combine`, preferably once ahead of time, to avoid lots of string concatenations
- check for sync-completion; in the callback, check `CompletedSynchronously` and exit immediately if `true`; when *starting* work, capture the `IAsyncResult`, check `CompletedSynchronously`, and process right away on the same thread if `true`
- *consider* moving to the newer async API - `ReceiveAsync` (this is quite a significant change, though)
- don't `MessageBox` from an IO method

Comment: Well, I have just started C#. Could you please show a small sample.

Comment: @hypheni of the `MemoryStream` buffer? sure, give me a sec to edit

Comment: Well thaks for the quick response. I got an example from http://www.dotnetperls.com/memorystream. Still it would be good if you can provide one.

Comment: But still, now I have to parse data from memory buffer. I want to know that. How do I parse upto <EOF> i.e. initial data sent by the client and have that in a single variable at server side.

Comment: @hypheni by copying the data into a `MemoryStream` at each "receive", when you get to the end: all the data *is in* the backlog. So: just read from there. BTW: reading to <EOF> isn't the "initial data" - it is **all** the data; if a socket is closed, no more data will ever be received.

Comment: Yes. I think thats what I need to do. So your point is read whole data in memory and then look for seperator from start point. Once that is found cut the data and process accordingly.

Comment: @hypheni that depends entirely on the data; personally, I always try to buffer as little data as possible; if by <EOF> you actually mean EOT (byte 04), then sure : you can trivially scan for that when receiving data and discard any header data; but that all comes down to "framing". I can't advise you on how to frame your data without your framing spec ;p